# Create Form don't submit

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I try to add a project with user as foreign key.
When I submit my frontend form, nothing happen.
I come back to my submission form page but projects are not registered in database.
I've got no error message even if my debug is on.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from template.models import Template
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from django.utils import timezone

def Project_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.user.username, filename)

def Project_uploads_directory_path(instance, imgs, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.user.username, imgs, filename)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Building')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
    #tags = models.OneToOneField(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=Project_directory_path)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mail = models.EmailField()
    focus1_titre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    focus1_text = models.TextField()
    focus1_img = models.FileField(upload_to=Project_uploads_directory_path)
    focus1_btn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    focus1_btn_link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class AddProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Project
    widgets = {"user": forms.HiddenInput()}
    fields = ('name', 'url', 'description', 'image', 'create_date', 'template', 'title', 'slogan', 'focus1_titre',
              'focus1_text', 'focus1_img', 'focus1_btn',
              'focus1_btn_link', 'focus2_titre', 'focus2_text', 'focus2_img', 'focus2_btn', 'focus3_titre',
              'focus3_text', 'focus3_img', 'focus3_btn', 'focus3_btn_link',
              'about_titre', 'about_text', 'about_img', 'prod1_titre', 'prod1_text', 'prod1_img', 'prod2_titre',
              'prod2_text', 'prod2_img', 'prod3_titre', 'prod3_text', 'prod3_img', 'adresse', 'phone', 'mail', 'twitter', 'facebook',
              'primaire', 'secondaire', 'title_font', 'text_font', )
```

views.py

```
class AddProjectView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/add_project.html'
    form_class = AddProjectForm

def get_initial(self):
    user = self.request.user
    initial = super().get_initial()
    initial['id'] = user.id
    return initial

def form_valid(self, form):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST,  request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        project = form.save(commit=False)  # this is missing in your views
        project.user = self.request.user.id
        project.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        project.url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        project.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        project.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        project.template = form.cleaned_data['template']
        project.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        project.slogan = form.cleaned_data['slogan']
        project.adresse = form.cleaned_data['adresse']
        project.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        project.mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']
        project.about_titre = form.cleaned_data['about_titre']
        project.about_text = form.cleaned_data['about_text']
        project.about_img = form.cleaned_data['about_img']
        project.focus1_titre = form.cleaned_data['focus1_titre']
        project.focus1_text = form.cleaned_data['focus1_text']
        project.focus1_img = form.cleaned_data['focus1_img']
        project.focus1_btn = form.cleaned_data['focus1_btn']
        project.focus1_btn_link = form.cleaned_data['focus1_btn_link']
        project.focus2_titre = form.cleaned_data['focus2_titre']
        project.focus2_text = form.cleaned_data['focus2_text']
        project.focus2_img = form.cleaned_data['focus2_img']
        project.focus2_btn = form.cleaned_data['focus2_btn']
        project.focus2_btn_link = form.cleaned_data['focus2_btn_link']
        project.focus3_titre = form.cleaned_data['focus3_titre']
        project.focus3_text = form.cleaned_data['focus3_text']
        project.focus3_img = form.cleaned_data['focus3_img']
        project.focus3_btn = form.cleaned_data['focus3_btn']
        project.focus3_btn_link = form.cleaned_data['focus3_btn_link']
        project.prod1_titre = form.cleaned_data['prod1_titre']
        project.prod1_text = form.cleaned_data['prod1_text']
        project.prod1_img = form.cleaned_data['prod1_img']
        project.prod2_titre = form.cleaned_data['prod2_titre']
        project.prod2_text = form.cleaned_data['prod2_text']
        project.prod2_img = form.cleaned_data['prod2_img']
        project.prod3_titre = form.cleaned_data['prod3_titre']
        project.prod3_text = form.cleaned_data['prod3_text']
        project.prod3_img = form.cleaned_data['prod3_img']
        project.twitter = form.cleaned_data['twitter']
        project.facebook = form.cleaned_data['facebook']
        project.primaire = form.cleaned_data['primaire']
        project.secondaire = form.cleaned_data['secondaire']
        project.title_font = form.cleaned_data['title_font']
        project.text_font = form.cleaned_data['text_font']

        project.save()
        messages.success(self.request, _('Project successfully created.'))
        return redirect('projects:add_project')
```

add_project.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/default/page.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<header id="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="header-text">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h1 class="white typed">{% trans 'Add project' %}</h1>
                        <span class="typed-cursor">|</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="cut cut-top"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row content-tables">
               <div id="error">
                {% if error %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>
                                {{error}}
                        </div>
                {% endif %}
                    <!--{% if message %}-->
                        <!--<div class="alert alert-success">-->
                            <!--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>-->
                                <!--{{message}}-->
                        <!--</div>-->
                    <!--{% endif %}-->
                </div>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form %}
                    <button class="btn btn-success">{% trans 'Register your project' %}</button>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I've rollback your edit: Please do not change a question into something that isn't a reproducible problem anymore. Instead, post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py,

```
class classname(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
     form_class = #addformname
     template_name = #addtemplatename

     def get(self, request):
          ---

     def post(self, request):
          form = self.form_class(request.POST, #add request.FILES if you are adding file)
          if form.is_valid():
              project = form.save(commit = False) #this is missing in your views
              project.user = self.request.user
              #add all your cleaned_data 
              project.save()
              return redirect(#add the path)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
Must get the logged user in def get(self, request): ?
with
user = self.request.user ?

Comment: I have made 
    [code]def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        return user[code]
and its return : local variable 'project' referenced before assignment

Comment: Does not require in get, you can add user in post as self.request.user.

Comment: i changed project.save() to form.save() and set user with 
user = self.request.user.id 
but raise a new error : 
The Project could not be created because the data didn't validate.
In post request "user" is empty

Comment: I have edited the answer to add user in post. As we have added project = form.save(commit = False), our form name now changed into project, for that I have added project.save().

Comment: now it raise error.

Exception Value: 
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
Exception Location: C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py in as_widget, line 93
In template C:\Users\celine\Documents\IDWEB\Projets\Diy\content\templates\layouts\default\page.html, error at line 21

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static "img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" %}">

The base template display good on other pages

Comment: solve the problem with server reload.
but back to 
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value: 
local variable 'project' referenced before assignment

for line 69 : last project.save()
and user post is still empty.
Users gestion is from [link]https://github.com/egorsmkv/simple-django-login-and-register/tree/master/source

Comment: I have edited the views.py to add corrections.
I have now the error
Cannot assign "2": "Project.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Instead self.request.user.id write only self.request.user, the other way is to use kwargs